# User Profile seems to reset constantly

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have a user on my domain that when she logs out, her profile seems to get removed and recreated. First it was `C:\Users\Username`, then `Username.Domain`, then `Username.Domain.000`, and the numbers kept going up and up.

I copied the data out of those folders to a safe folder, removed the user profiles and their folders, then had the user log in again to recreate a fresh one. I copied the data back to her new profile, and things seemed to be good.

This weekend passed, and she logged in again this morning to a fresh desktop. I checked the Application Logs, and I saw a weird entry:

`Windows Search Service indexed data for user "<domain>\<Username>" successfully removed in response to user profile deletion`. I've never seen this issue before, so I Googled. I found out we are supposed to delete the profile from `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, but I'd like to find the actual *cause* of this issue. Why is the profile getting deleted? I'm not seeing anything else in the Event Log relating to this.

Comment: Does this user always use the same device to log into the domain?

Comment: Same device, connected via Ethernet cable - So, no wireless interference, and no weird travelling machine syndrome

Comment: As you have a backup of user files I'd probably cut your losses trying to resolve it and re-image the workstation. The problem is linked to Windows trying not to lose your data by creating temporary profiles. It isn't deleting them. This is a preventative measure by Microsoft. You can fix it by following the registry fix ("ProfileList"). It will be a mismatch of profile loaded and actual profile location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were two possibilities that caused this: the first was a Group Policy setting, the second was a start up script malfunctioning.

For the Group Policy, check under Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> User Profiles. There are two options there to check: *Delete cached copies of roaming profiles* and *Delete user profiles older than a specified number of days on system restart*. I changed both of these back to Not Configured.

Secondly, the startup script that ran only half-assed the profile deletion. I removed the script as well, and the profiles stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! 3 years later and I just had a user who is ***very*** change-averse that lost their entire profile due to that GPO setting. I can't recover the profile b/c it isn't roaming and we don't back up the individual machine profiles, but at least it shouldn't ever happen again now that I've disabled the setting. I can only assume that Microsoft, in their "infinite wisdom" trying to be "helpful" enabled that setting with an update somewhere along the way b/c I *know* that I didn't set it myself. *C'est la vie*

Answer (score 0):

I've seen roaming profiles do this when connection/authentication to the server is lost.  Local profile issues like this can be indicative of hard disk errors or permissions.

Comment: I've run `chkdsk c: /f /r`, and no errors there. It shouldn't be a roaming profile, as we don't use a Windows Server, just Samba with a simple `/home` folder for each user.

Answer (score 0):

`Username` and `Username.Domain` are caused by logging in with a local account and a domain account with the same name (and possibly the same password).  I've only seen the .000 used when there is an profile corruption, deletion and recreation, or a user rename followed by creating a user the old name again (basically any time windows tries to create a profile and there is already one using that path--often because profile paths are NOT renamed when the username is changed).

Comment: But the issue is that her stuff is simply GONE, as in, not even in C:\Users anymore

Comment: Did you install the OS yourself from retail discs?  There are many setups where admins intentionally set up this behavior to happen on every logout or on a schedule.

Comment: I am the admin, and none of my other systems have this behavior from the same image running on 90 other systems

Comment: +1 on your question, then.  That's very strange.